# filecontents cannot write my text

Tags: filecontents

i want to save a text to a file using the filecontents package. Here is the source code:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.lst}
Hello World!
\end{filecontents}
```

A file "test.lst" is created, but it is empty. If I use the source code

```
    \begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.lst}
Hello World!
\end{filecontents*}
```

then the header

```
%% LaTeX2e file `test.lst'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `javaprogrammierung' on 2021/04/08.
%%
```

is written into the file, but not the text "Hello World!".

Can someone help me, why no text is written? I am using MacTeX 2021.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Soener

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full but  minimal example so we know exactly what you are doing. Note that filecontents is in the kernel, no package needed.

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The manual of the [`filecontents` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents?) states the following on the first page (see also  daleif's comment below your question).

[image]

> **Notice**
> The version of LaTeX released in Fall 2019 incorporates all of
> this package’s functionality (and more) into the LaTeX kernel itself.
> As a result, there is no longer a need for the `filecontents` package.
> Please use the new, built-in `filecontents` environment instead.

Update your LaTeX installation (if necessary) and start with the following minimal example (taken from the manual) and tell us if you still have problems.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{myfile.tex}
This text gets written to \texttt{myfile.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now it works. Thank you.